# Reporting Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I am using kibana 6.5.4 which means that I should be able to see the reporting tab in my kibana as Xpack should've already been installed. However, the reporting tab is not shown.

[image]

[image]

I've followed these instructions to enable reporting

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-settings-kb.html#reporting-kibana-server-settings

When I set the property in my kibana.yml like below

```
xpack.reporting.enabled: true
```

I get the following error when attempting to start kibana.

```
  error  [11:30:40.296] [fatal][root] Error: "xpack.reporting.enabled" 
  setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that 
  expected plugins are installed.
  at KbnServer.exports.default 
  (/usr/local/Cellar/kibana/6.5.4/src/server/config/complete.js:21:17)
  at KbnServer.mixin 
  (/usr/local/Cellar/kibana/6.5.4/src/server/kbn_server.js:170:16)
  at <anonymous>

 FATAL  Error: "xpack.reporting.enabled" setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed.
```

I don't understand, as per docs Xpack should be automatically installed with kibana since 6.3+?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error message, and you are correct X-Pack is installed by default now - can you provide more of the `kibana.yml` file for review, and how Kibana was installed (Docker image, RPM, etc.)?

Additionally, based on the screenshot, you're looking for reporting inside of Discover - this would present itself under the 'Share' heading, not a unique one.  Ref:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-reporting.html

Comment: I am using AWS ElasticSearch which doesn't have x-pack, I am not sure that could be the reason? I've added a screenshot (see above)

Comment: You *can* install X-Pack on just Kibana, but this will only give you access to a subset of features.  Try simply removing the `xpack.reporting.enabled` from your `kibana.yml` - I tested a basic install using just the Basic license and was able to access reporting from within the `Share` tab of Discover.